# how to find all "1401\/07\/29 19:00:00" pattern in a text with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

i have a text that contain "1401/07/29 19:00:00" pattern.
how find all top pattern in text with re.findall method in python

Comment: Please add a sample text along with what you are trying to match.

Comment: Are there literal backslashes in your text file? The title shows them, the post does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `string = "1401/07/29 19:00:00"`

```
re.findall(r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', string)
```

if `string = '1401\/07\/29 19:00:00'`

```
string = '1401\/07\/29 19:00:00'

#variant 1
print(re.findall(r'\d{4}\\/\d{2}\\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', string)) 
#output: ['1401\\/07\\/29 19:00:00']

#variant 2
print(re.findall(r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', string.replace("\\",'' ))) 
#output: ['1401/07/29 19:00:00']
```

Comment: tnx for answer but it not work. i have "fromSiteShowDate":"1401\/07\/29 19:00:00" text. i use your answer but not work

Comment: this `"fromSiteShowDate":"1401\/07\/29 19:00:00"` looks like dictionary item, are you sure this is a string?

Comment: yes looks like dictionary but is a text.its between ' '.means: '  "fromSiteShowDate":"1401\/07\/29 19:00:00"  '

Comment: I've appended my answer, try the second part

Comment: tnx. its work for me